# Map function in C++ with templates

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

I'm trying to learn templates in C++ and one of the things I was trying was to code a map function like the ones you typically find in functional languages. The idea was something like this:

```
template <class X> X * myMap(X * func(X), X * array, int size)
    {
      X * temp;
      for(int i = 0, i < size, i++) {temp[i] = (*func)(array[i]);}
      return temp;
    }
```

But when I try to use this in:

```
int test(int k) { return 2 * k;}
int main(void)
{
   int k[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   int *q = new int[5];
   q = myMap(&test, k, 5);
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {cout << q[i];}
   delete [] q;
   return 0;
}
```

I got a type mismatch error when compiling:

```
 main.cpp:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘myMap(int (*)(int), int [5], int)’
```

I tried to change it to:

```
int main(void)
{
   int *k = new int[5];
   int *q = new int[5];
   for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {k[i] = i;}
   q = myMap(&test, k, 5);
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {cout << q[i];}
   delete [] q;
   return 0;
}
```

The error message changes to:

```
 main.cpp:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘myMap(int (*)(int), int*&, int)’
```

This is probably something very wrong, but I can't find where.

EDIT: The errors where:
1) I mistyped the pointer to function. It's  X (*func)(X) instead of X * func(X) .
2) forgot to allocate temp. Must do `X * temp = new X[size]`.
3) are there any more errors?

Comment: you know this function already exists in the standard library, right? (called `std::transform`)

Comment: oh yeah, I was just trying to learn how to do this.

Comment: You're not allocating any memory for the newly created array.

Comment: Also you can make your function more general by changing the type to `template <class X, class Y> Y * myMap(Y (*func)(X), X * array, int size)` or even `template <class X, class Y, class F> Y * myMap(F func, X * array, int size)`.

Comment: That last version look beautiful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just getting the syntax for a function pointer wrong here.  You want to say:

```
template <class X> 
X* myMap(X (* func)(X), X * array, int size)
{
    ...
}
```

To make this function more generic, use a template parameter instead of a function pointer so you can use both plain function pointers *and* C++ function objects (functors).

```
template <class X, class F> 
X* myMap(F func, X * array, int size)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to compile this second version. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 5):

`X * func(X)` does not say what you think it says.  You want `X (*func)(X)`.

Comment: oops... Damn. I knew it had to be somthing stupid. But now I got a segfault. :(

Comment: Just figured I forgot to allocate the temp variable;

Answer (score 1):

You were very close.  Just missing parens around `X(*func)(X)`.  Couple other syntax errors, fixed here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <class X> X * myMap(X(*func)(X), X * array, int size)
    {
      X * temp;
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {temp[i] = (*func)(array[i]);}
      return temp;
    }

int test(int k) { return 2 * k;}
int main(void)
{
   int k[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   int *q = new int[5];
   q = myMap(&test, k, 5);
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {cout << q[i];}
   delete [] q;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I had to annotate the type when calling the function. Is that necessary? Also, I'm getting a segfault from this code. Just figured I forgot to allocate the temp variable;

Comment: @Rafael:  No, I don't think you *need* to annotate the type.  The compiler should be able to deduce it.  I'll edit my post.

Answer (score -2):

You're not calling your templated MyMap function, you'reattempting to call a non-templated MyMap function. Try q= MyMap(.....)